# I used apt-get to download irssi and it got stored in /usr/bin and I can't find it/open it. How to solve this?

Tags: command-line, apt

I used

> apt-get install irssi.

to install the IRSSI. But I didn't find it anywhere. Not even if I search for it in Activities. If I try to install it again it says it's already installed. So looks like I did install it but I can't find it!

So I searched the web for "can't find a progam I installed" and it told me "it's probably in /usr/bin". And it is. But how do I open it? And do I have to be in sudo to open it everytime?

This is the location:

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1052600 mar  6 14:03  irssi

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to launch it with the terminal with `irssi`? and if you see problem with permission, so you need the `sudo` (`sudo irssi`)

Comment: Launching it with just > irssi works! I'm dumb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your information, I usually confirm first if a package has been installed with a command:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep irssi
```

To check which files were installed with it I use:

```
$ dpkg -L irssi
```

I have just double checked and installed the IRC client - what you need to do is to open a terminal and run it from a command line:

```
$ irssi
```

After that the program has started as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it from a terminal, just write `irssi`. /usr/bin is included in the PATH variable that tell's the system where to find executables.

If it is a gui program, you should be able to search for it in the desktop, or find it in the program menu.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to need a GUI. This is still very rough to me... I just want  to connect to an IRC ahah

Comment: You mean like [Quassel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Quassel)? :-)

Comment: Something like that, yes. Do you know that if I registered my nick with NickServ I can use it in Quassel?